# For each structure in php backend shows each card smaller and smaller. What should I do?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm currently working on a task for school, at the moment I'm stuck at the for each structure. I'm looking for a solution to make the cards the same width and height and 5 cards on each line.[What it looks like at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMcSJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyBrL.png)
This is my code.

```
<?php

foreach($arrFietsen as $fietsen){
echo "<div class='card-deck col-lg-10 mx-auto pb-5 pt-5'>";
echo "<div class='card'>";
echo"<h5 class='align-self-center position-absolute p-2'>".$fietsen->merk."</h5>";
echo" <img class='card-img-top' src='.$fietsen->img' alt='Card image cap'>";
echo"<div class='card-footer'>";
echo" <small class='text-muted'>".$fietsen->verkoopprijs."</small>";
echo" <button type='button' class='btn float-right btn-warning'>Check</button>";
echo"</div>";
echo"</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: The thing that strikes me is that you have three open divs and only close two. In a loop that makes a big mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ident the code you'll see that a cloding div is missing, that makes this divs with class `col-lg-10` and padding nest:

```
<?php
foreach ($arrFietsen as $fietsen) {
   echo "<div class='card-deck col-lg-10 mx-auto pb-5 pt-5'>";
      echo "<div class='card'>";
      echo"<h5 class='align-self-center position-absolute p-2'>".$fietsen->merk."</h5>";
      echo" <img class='card-img-top' src='.$fietsen->img' alt='Card image cap'>";
         echo"<div class='card-footer'>";
            echo" <small class='text-muted'>".$fietsen->verkoopprijs."</small>";
            echo" <button type='button' class='btn float-right btn-warning'>Check</button>";
         echo"</div>";
      echo"</div>";
    echo"</div>"; // this is missing
}
?>
```

Comment: That helped thanks but I still can't put 5 cards on the same line and the other 5 under them.